# Match keys from two dictionaries, and make new dictionary with matched key and two associated values

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

So I have two dictionaries:

```
dic1 = {1.0: 9.0, 3.0: 33.0, 5.0: 13.0}
dic2 = {1.0: 3.4, 3.0: 88.9, 4.0: 73.0, 5.0: 9.0}
```

The keys in each are the ID number, the values in dic1 are rating and the values in dic2 are cost.

What I want is a way to associated each ID number with both its cost and rating and in the process delete any keys dic2 that do not have a match in dic1.

```
dic3 = {1.0: (9.0, 4.2), 3.0: (33.0, 88.9), 5.0: (13.0, 9.0)}
```

I then would like to be able to create an array with columns ID, cost, rating.

I haven't been able to think of a way to do this.  Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: There's a mistake in the expected output, the value for key `1.0` should be `(9.0, 3.4)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, which will work on old versions of Python (older than 2.7):

```
dic3 = {}
for k in dic1.viewkeys() & dic2.viewkeys():
    dic3[k] = (dic1[k], dic2[k])
```

Or this, an approach that will work on recent versions of Python (>= 2.7 but < 3.0), using dictionary comprehensions:

```
dic3 = { k : (dic1[k], dic2[k]) for k in dic1.viewkeys() & dic2.viewkeys() }
```

In Python 3.0 and up the keys are already treated as sets, yielding the nicest solution:

```
dic3 = { k : (dic1[k], dic2[k]) for k in dic1.keys() & dic2.keys() }
```

Anyway, the trick to determine the keys common to both dictionaries is to intersect their sets, and it works as expected:

```
dic3
=> {1.0: (9.0, 3.4), 3.0: (33.0, 88.9), 5.0: (13.0, 9.0)}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
dic3 = {k : (v1, dic2[k]) for k, v1 in dic1.items() if k in dic2}
```

Comment: Yup, that's cleaner than using a set :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use a dict-comprehension, `dic1.viewkeys() & dic2.viewkeys()` returns a set of all common keys from the two dictionaries:

```
>>> dic1 = {1.0: 9.0, 3.0: 33.0, 5.0: 13.0}
>>> dic2 = {1.0: 3.4, 3.0: 88.9, 4.0: 73.0, 5.0: 9.0}
>>> {k : (dic1[k],dic2[k])  for k in dic1.viewkeys() & dic2.viewkeys()}
{1.0: (9.0, 3.4), 3.0: (33.0, 88.9), 5.0: (13.0, 9.0)}
```

For py2.6 and earlier use `dict()`:

```
>>> dict( (k , (dic1[k],dic2[k]))  for k in dic1.viewkeys() & dic2.viewkeys())
{1.0: (9.0, 3.4), 3.0: (33.0, 88.9), 5.0: (13.0, 9.0)}
```

On py3.x use just `dict.keys()`:

```
>>> {k : (dic1[k],dic2[k])  for k in dic1.keys() & dic2.keys()}
{1.0: (9.0, 3.4), 3.0: (33.0, 88.9), 5.0: (13.0, 9.0)}
```